# Preencher um Grafico (chart) com dados de um vetor

Tags: php, google-charts

Sou novo aqui e essa é minha primeira pergunta, estou iniciando em PHP e queria saber como posso preencher um CHART com variáveis recebidas por um array.

Minha amostra de código é a seguinte:

```
<?php
$datacomp = date('d/m/y');
$consulta=mysql_query("SELECT SOBRECONSUMO_DIA, DATA_I FROM `atividades` WHERE SOBRECONSUMO = 1 and SOBRECONSUMO_DIA <> NULL");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($consulta);
do {
        $valor[$x]=$rows['SOBRECONSUMO_DIA'];
        $data[$x]=$rows['DATA_I'];
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> var x = '"$x"'var valor[x]='".$valor[$x]"' var data[x]='".$data[$x]"'}</script>";
} while ($rows= mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
```

E o código JS que vai ser executado depois do acima é esse:

```
$(function () {
    for (var i; x=i;i++)
    {
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart',
        data: [{
            period: data[x],
            valor de consumo: valor[x],
        }
]})
```

Sei que ta errado, mas eu preciso saber de uma forma de executar esse loop para jogar os dados para o Chart. VALEU!

Comment: Onde você trafega os dados do `PHP` pra página? Tem que usar ajax, já ouviu falar?

Comment: Eu até li umas coisas sobre o Ajax, pensei que nesse caso não fosse preciso usar.

Comment: Com onde eu trafego vc quer saber de onde vem?

Comment: Sim,você precisa transportá-los por Ajax e inserir no Gráfico.

Comment: teria alguma referência (link, trecho de código) como exemplo pra eu saber como fazer isso?

Comment: achei bem interessante esse [tutorial](http://tutsmais.com.br/blog/ajax/json-ajax-php-jquery/)